# Drupal Site Migration from FreeBSD 12 to Ubuntu 18.04 SQL database unknown behavior

Tags: 7, database, caching, migrations

I am currently trying to migrate the Drupal Site from FreeBSD 12 to Ubuntu 18.04. All the configurations are copied and moved to Ubuntu 18.04. Everything seems fine and I was able to create the Drupal Site with Ubuntu 18.04, but whenever I clear the cache on the new site, it seems like the page settings are gone and the content goes all over the place. Also, the newest content gets erased as well. I usually use mysqldump command line to dump the mysql database and restore the backup with the mysql command line. I have also tried downloading phpmyadmin to dump and restore the mysql database, but the issue is still present. This is a critical issue on the site, because installing a new module automatically deletes  cache.

Drupal Version: 7.59

I am guessing when the mysql database is dumped, the newest content and page settings goes into cache..? I am not really familiar on how mysql saves the database. Any help would be a great help for me to proceed with the migration. Thank you!

Comment: Disable **all caching**, including Drupal core, contrib modules, PHP, MySQL, memcached, reverse proxies, etc. If the problem goes away, then enable one at a time until the problem comes back. Don't assume only one is to blame, it could be how two or more interact with each other. Enable the MySQL general log to log all queries. Use it to see if inserts/updates are being sent to the database, and what queries run when the new data disappears. Insert a new node and use a SQL query to see if it was added to the node table (use the title to select just it)...

Comment: Use a MySQL client that runs queries directly on MySQL. PHPMyAdmin uses the webserver and PHP, which may be part of the problem. I like HeidiSQL on Windows for quick checks/debugging. It can use SSH so you don't have to open MySQL to the internet. `All the configurations are copied and moved to Ubuntu 18.04` Do you mean you've made zero changes to the config files? You need to use a copy of the database. I'm assuming folders and security are different in Ubuntu and FreeBSD. Temporarily disable SELinux. Look at the (error) logs for Apache/Nginx, MySQL, PHP, SELinux, Ubuntu's system log, etc.